# Simple nonlinear regression for gaussian peak

Tags: regression, markov-chain-montecarlo

I want to do non-linear Bayesian Regression, my setup is almost exactly the same as the [linear case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_linear_regression):

I have a signal encoded as $y_i \in \mathbb{R}$ given $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$ for $i = 1\dots N$ and I want to do inference for a very simple model $y_i = a + b x_i + c \exp(-(x_i-\mu)^2/\sigma^2) + \epsilon_i$ where $\epsilon_i$ is i.i.d gaussian noise. The priors for $a, b, c, \mu, \sigma$ are pretty much any noninformative priors for which $c>0$ is ensured.

I simply want to sample from the posterior of the model. I don't really care about the method, could be closed-form or some mcmc algorithm, the faster the better.

I'm sure that this problem is already well studied in the literature, but I can't seem to find it. I would appreciate pointers to papers or books. Thanks!

Comment: [stan](https://mc-stan.org/), [rstan](https://mc-stan.org/users/interfaces/rstan) [brms](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/index.html) [pystan](https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ...

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!